# Building customizable start page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I'm in a search for some jQuery resources or other things that will help me building a customizable start page for users.
I'm talking about tiles that have to be aligned reasonably in the screen (usually a parent div).
The tiles have equal size and if possible I want to let the user drag them for customization (Not a must).
The main issue is aligning the tiles in a rasonable way.
I found some jQuery plugins like freewall etc. but they usually try to fill an area and less appropriate for my cause...

Comment: something like this [here](http://gridster.net/demos/multiple-grids.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

When you using Freewall you can choice option for not fill by set:

**fixSize: 0**

even you can control the gaps too, by using method setHoles.
please check there links for know how to control the gaps:

http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/404.html

http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/

Best

Answer (score 0):

I've found a very appropriate plugin:
http://masonry.desandro.com/ 
It's capaable of performing layout and placing the tiles centered in the given space. 
Perfect for me.